# Seeking advice on copying Peano's notation

Tags: notation, math-software

Can anyone give me advice, or a URL for advice, on simulating the notation of Peano's Formulario in LaTeX? or in Word?

Comment: I don't know what the notation looks like, but you could try drawing it here: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: For LaTeX question consider asking at http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: @martini  Is there some etiquette to follow about asking on two stackexchanges?

Comment: I do not know, but I would mention the other post on both sites.

Answer (score 0):

All there seems to be currently is an answer for his set inclusion symbol.  See  [How to reproduce the "old" Peano's symbol for set inclusion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20381/how-to-reproduce-the-old-peanos-symbol-for-set-inclusion)